# PIC16F887 Timer0 counting overflows

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip

I'm using the PIC16F887 44-pin Demo board.

I'm trying to do this

1. User presses switch
2. Timer Starts
3. If within 3 seconds, the switch is pressed again turn on LED 0 else turn on LED 1

Since the Timer0 with a prescaler set to 255, will overflow after 65536 μs I need to count the number of times it overflows and check whether it reaches that amount.
That would be 46 times.

These are the relevant extracts of my code

```
movlw     B'10000111'         ; configure Prescaler on Timer0, max prescale (/256)
movwf     OPTION_REG          ; configure
MOVLW     B'10100000'         ; enable Timer 0 and global interrupts
MOVWF     INTCON

MainLoop:
BTFSS     PORTB,0             ; is the switch pressed (0)
GOTO      EndMainLoop         ; Lights up LED 0
MOVF      TimerCount, w                 
XORLW     .46                 ; Check whether XOR TimerCount with 46
BTFSS     STATUS,Z            ; returns a 0
GOTO      MainLoop
GOTO      State2              ; Lights up LED 1
```

TimerCount gets incremented in the Interrupt section of the code as shown below

```
org 4
ServiceTimer0:
 bcf       STATUS,RP0          ; Ensure ISR executes in Register Bank 0
 bcf       STATUS,RP1
 BCF       INTCON,T0IF         ; clear the interrupt flag.
 INCF      TimerCount,f        ; Increment TimerCount
 RETFIE                        ; Return from the interrupt
```

However Timer0 never overflows and the interrupt routine is never called for some reason. 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't work, because you didn't select right memory bank!
Try...

```
movlw     B'10000001'         ; configure Prescaler on Timer0, max prescale (/256)
BANKSEL   OPTION_REG
movwf     OPTION_REG          ; configure
movlw     B'10100000'         ; enable Timer 0 and global interrupts
movwf     INTCON
BANKSEL   0
...
```

And your ISR doesn't save and restore STATUS flags, so your program can't work correct!